# Changing the optional argument of a package at some point in the document

Tags: package-options, footmisc

Is it possible to change the optional argument from `<option 1>` to `<option 2>` (given to a loaded package `<package>` via `\usepackage[<option x>]{<package>}`) at an *arbitrary* point in the document, so that **until** this point `option 1` applies and **after** that point `option 2` does?

I want to illustrate my question with an example:

Let's say the ´footmisc´-package (providing layouting-options etc. for footnotes) is loaded and I want to use the `side`-option (which causes footnotes to appear in the margin as "`\marginpar`s") for, let's say, chapter 2 *only*.

Is there a way to realise such "option changes" or are workarounds needed for such a case?
(In this particular example custom commands adding `marginpar`s instead of "normal footnotes")?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! Feel free to visit our [TeX.SX starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to get the most out of this site.

Comment: Most packages allow this. The package `footmisc` not. You have to do the definition manual.

Comment: There is no general way. It really depends on what is done by the specific package when you set the specific option if and how you can revert/undo the option.

Comment: @PeterJansson: Thanks, I already went through the guide. :)

@MarcoDaniel: Haha, a good choice, so to speak. Okay, I'll be looking for a manual solution...

@cgnieder: Packages which allow that would be `geometry` or `fancyhdr` for example - am I right?

Comment: @LCsa there are quite a number of packages which provide a setup command that can be used anywhere to change the options, for example `siunitx`. I'm not that familiar with `geometry` and `fancyhdr` so I can't comment on them. It really depends: maybe an option just sets a boolean switch which could be reversed manually, maybe an option includes some kind of config file which could not be undone...

Comment: @cgnieder: Okay, I see! So, generally speaking, if the package doesn't provide you with a `\setup blabla`-command (or something similar) it is not possible to change those once given options at a time later in the document. At least not for ordinary mortals (=non-LaTeX-experts :P)...

Comment: @LCsa In many cases and for many options there may be things one could do, probably after looking at the package source to figure out what the option does. If that helps of course depends on your level of expertise :)

Comment: For me, workarounds are the ones, it seems. :P
I spent a lot of time "exploring" LaTeX these days and I'm glad about my developing "higher but still low"-skills.^^ Thanks to this site, mostly, I managed to "implement" one or the other little function in my document. :)
So, thanks for (all of) your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a package option can be reverted/unset and how that may be done is a per-case question. It depends on what exactly the package in question does if the specific option in question is set. Package options generally don't have anything in common except that they're given as package options.

An option may simply set a boolean flag...

```
% somewhere in mypackage.sty
\newif\ifmypackage@myoption
\DeclareOption{myoption}{\mypackage@myoptiontrue}
```

... which could be reverted by saying `\mypackage@myoptionfalse` and could give the desired effect. But if that actually has the desired effect depends on what is done with that flag by the package. If the flag has only been used in an `\edef` for example setting the flag to false may have no effect at all.

An option may also load an additional file, some configuration or definition file, say. If that's the case there is no way to “unload” the file and hence no way to revert the option. Although one may be able to revert what ever is done in that file. It depends...

And there loads of other possibilities...

Some packages provide setup commands which allow to set their options anywhere in the document, though. But even then this might not work for every option the package has. Maybe some of them are load-time options only...

Long story short: unless you have a specific package and a specific option in mind the answer is: definitely maybe.